# In-app billing crash

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

My ios app crashes with in-app billing, in the following line:
[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutRemovals:]

Using swift and app delegate is SKProductsRequestDelegate and SKPaymentTransactionObserver

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please provide the error message and related code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to put the

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
```

in the dealloc method. This will tell the SKPaymentQueue that the RemoveAdsViewController will not listen to any transactions after it has been deallocated.